# Lowercase string but dont touch the first letter of each single word

Tags: php

Basically, say I have this string:

```
BolTer LoToRoX iZ No GOud
```

I only want to lowercase everything after the first letter of each word, like so

```
Bolter Lotorox iz No Goud
```

I've tried messing around with `ucfirst`, `ucwords` and `strtolower` for a while now.

```
ucfirst(strtolower($str));
```

Would give me

```
Bolter lotorox iz no goud
```

and

```
ucwords(strtolower($str));
```

would give me

```
Bolter Lotorox Iz No Goud
```

Which is no "goud" for me.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is what you're after:

```php
<?php

function custom_lowercase( $string )
{
    // Explode the string by space
    $parts = explode( ' ', $string );

    // Return first character of each part and lowercase of the remaining parts
    $parts = array_map( function($a) {
        return mb_substr( $a, 0, 1 ) . strtolower( mb_substr( $a, 1 ) );
    }, $parts );

    // Return imploded string
    return implode( ' ', $parts );
}

$string = 'BolTer LoToRoX iZ No GOud';

echo "Original: " . $string . "<br />";
echo "Custom lowercase: " . custom_lowercase( $string );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty

```
<?php
   $str = 'BolTer LoToRoX iZ No GOud';
   $words = explode(' ',$str);
   $out = array();
   foreach ($words as $w) {
    $len = strlen($w);
    $nw = $w[0];
    $nw.=strtolower(substr($w,1));
    $out[]=$nw;         
   }
   $new_string = implode(' ',$out);
   echo $new_string;
   die;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   echo implode(' ', 
                array_map(function($i) { return $i[0] . strtolower(substr($i, 1)); },
                          explode(' ', $str)));  // Bolter Lotorox iz No Goud
```